# Query on returning locally scoped objects in python

Tags: python

Below is the program that returns `function` type object  defined in function `f` whose stack frame(`f1`) is still alive until the program exits.

[image]

---

Below is the program that returns `int` type object whose value is 1024, but the stack frame does not exist after we return `int` type object?

[image]

---

As per the above two diagrams, Why this difference in return type mechanisms, where frame is not alive, when you return `int` type object.

What is the idea for stack frame being alive when `function` type object is returned?

Comment: The distinction made in the diagrams is that functions are *mutable objects*, while integers are not. But both are returned as references...

Comment: You have to be really careful when arguing with small integers < 256, as they are globally interned. Also, in the second example your just passing `n` through, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @filmor  What I would like to confirm is, In second example,  Does `add_three`  refer to same `int` object that `n` is pointing to? This is where I am asking whether the return mechanism is by copy? For simplicity, assume the value is > 256.

Comment: Yes, it does. When calling the function you are passing a reference to the object, that you return unchanged in the end. If you'd do something like `n *= 1` the returned object would be different, as that changed the reference `n`. This is where the small integer optimisation is important, since `id(n * 1) == id(n)` iff `n` is a small integer.

Answer (score 4):

Python never make copies unless explicitly asked to (for example, slicing a list does ask Python to copy that part of the list, shallowly).

"Does add_three refer to same int object that n is pointing to?" -- yes, only references to that `int` are being passed around and held in frames.  In this case this applies whatever the value of `n`.

Any Python implementation is allowed to keep a single copy, or multiple copies, of immutable objects line `int`s -- whatever's most convenient to that implementation, given the semantics are not affected anyway.

So in a given implementation it could happen that every mention of literal `3` refers to the same `int` object but mentions of literal `333` need not.  E.g:

```
2>>> a=333; b=333; print(id(a), id(b))
(4298804944, 4298804944)
2>>> a=333
2>>> b=333
2>>> print(id(a), id(b))
(4298753600, 4298753336)
```

The semantics of the two cases are absolutely identical; in the first case the compiler (intrinsically called on the whole line at once) finds it handy to instantiate and use a single `int` worth `333`, in the second case it prefers to make and use two such instances -- either is completely fine, given `int`'s immutability (same goes for other number types, strings, tuples, frozen sets -- but not for mutable types).

Note that when the Python specification refers to "same semantics", it explicitly includes introspection, which may be able to pinpoint implementation differences between semantically equivalent states.

`id` (normally returning the memory address of an object, in current popular implementations of Python, but in any case an id that's unique per object as long as the object lives, per language specs) is introspection, as consequently is the `is` operator.  So you can if you wish use it to understand some optimizations a given implementation may perform, or not.

So on to your other Qs: "Is my understanding correct?" -- no.
"Why this difference" -- `def` builds a function object, which is mutable, so any `def` even with identical function definitions must return a new object, just like e.g `[]` builds a list object, mutable, so any `[]` must return a new object.  `3` build an `int` object, which is immutable, so any `3` is allowed (per language rules) to return either the same or a new object.

One more question was added in an edit: "What is the idea for stack frame being alive when function type object is returned?"

Answer: every object stays alive as long as it's reachable.  An outer function's frame, in particular, stays alive as long as inner (nested) functions is returned, if they refer to names in the outer frame.

(Any Python implementation doesn't **have** to garbage-collect objects that don't any more need to be alive -- it may delay that garbage collection as long as it pleases, or can perform it at once -- implementation details!-).

Comment: @overexchange, ok, but there's nothing in your edit that in any way invalidates my A or needs any addition -- it's **exactly** what I explained in my A.  You apparently don't like my A, but neither do you give any indication of what you think it leaves unanswered!  Ah well, I'll edit to remove the last, now-unneeded para.

Comment: @overexchange, added answer to your new and somewhat unrelated question.

Comment: why `function` type objects are chosen to be mutable and `int` type objects are chosen to be immutable? Am still not clear, How mutable/immutable factor has something to do with existence of frame `f1`?

Comment: @overexchange, all numbers and strings are immutable by design for the same design decisions Java took years later -- it's handier and faster and allows effective hash tables (dictionaries and sets, in Python).  The outer frame of `g` is not reachable, so any Python implementation could choose to garbage collect it if if wanted -- if yours doesn't, it's an implementation-convenience choice.  The only effect of functions being mutable is no implementation's allowed to return the same obj for `result1` and `result2`, as changes to one can't affect the other (`def` creates a new function obj).

Comment: Now I understand the meaning of function objects being mutable. But When you say, *could choose to garbage collect*, Does that mean, if `n` was not used in function `g` garbage collector could have deleted outer frame of `g` which is `f1` as mentioned in my first diagram? Am still not clear, why garbage collector did not delete frame `f1`

Comment: Any Python interpreter implementation can choose what garbage collection mechanism it wants to use -- as long as it never removes a reachable object, it can take its sweet time removing unreachable ones (e.g Jython does so by delegating to the underlying JVM's own GC).  Anyway, I'm not sure what kind of introspection you've done to determine that frame is still alive in this case -- or whether you're studying Python, the language (which leaves many degrees of freedom to its implementation), or a specific implementation.